# Magento Import multiple custom options using magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I want to import two custom option for single product in magento using magmi.

Comment: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options checkout these link

Comment: in this link only one custom option will be imported, i want to multiple custom option for single product

Comment: I think you should try by using ; in between 2 of them

Comment: i am using below format but still same problem:
sku Blouse Stitching:checkbox:0;Lining:field:0:1
JKSPR1606_1019 price:fixed:500;price:fixed:100

Comment: i got solution as mention below csv format sku  first custom option :checkbox:0:2 second custom option:field:0:1

Answer (score -1):

i got solution as mention below csv format sku first custom option :checkbox:0:2 second custom option:field:0:1